# Can you download a 360 degree video from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, download, 360-degrees

A few years ago I was still able to download Facebook 360 degree videos WITH the 360 degree function intact just using basic downloader like 4Kdownloader. Either the encryption in Facebook changed, or something else had changed, but now the video that gets downloaded is always flattened and doesn't preserve the 360 degree container.

Is there a way to get 360 degree videos from Facebook? The available tools can download 360 degree videos from Youtube and 360 *photos* from Facebook, but I haven't been able to find a way to donwload Facebook
s 360 videos.

Comment: If you can get the video, you can re-inject the spatial data into the container.  https://github.com/google/spatial-media/tree/master/spatialmedia

Comment: @Brad As it turns out, the video downloads flat in a layout that is a bit odd, and simply reinjecting the metadata doesn't work. For some reason the sky and the floor parts are separated from the side panorama as two circles.

Comment: This is how it looks like [link](https://ibb.co/WySVcGZ)

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen someone do 360 projection like that.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, I'm not sure if it's Facebook encryption messing up with it or the downloader just doesn't know how to parse it, because 360 degree videos from Youtube that got downloaded flat doesn't look like that. I tried downloading the same Facebook video with a different downloader and it now looks like this: [link](https://ibb.co/0jMxR2q)